# How to get number from promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why does typescript says?

> let shouldbeNumber: number Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type
>   'number'.Vetur(2322)

`turnIntoNumber`will always get strings of numbers such as **1,2,3,4,5,6...** , so I know `shouldbeNumber` will always be a number. How can I convince typescript or develop this piece of code?  :-)

```ts
async function makeMagic() {
  let shouldbeNumber: number = await turnIntoNumber("2");
}
function turnIntoNumber(get) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let shouldbeNumber : number =  Number(get);
    resolve(shouldbeNumber);
  });
}
```

Would you please help me to turn this javascript into a better typescript?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotate the functions return type

```
function turnIntoNumber(get) : Promise<number> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let shouldbeNumber : number =  Number(get);
    resolve(shouldbeNumber);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is an accurate answer, but it should be noted that current TypeScript will not always coerce types in the way, say, C# generally will. It is often still possible to get an input and output that do not match the expected, not just at run-time but often including mismatches within the code itself, causing havoc in medium to large code-bases. Again this isn't a problem with the answers, per se, but in my experience sometimes it's important to understand the larger picture when solving individual problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can annotate the type of `resolve`:

```
async function makeMagic() {
  let shouldbeNumber: number = await turnIntoNumber("2");
}
function turnIntoNumber(get) {
  return new Promise((resolve: (value: number) => void, reject) => {
    let shouldbeNumber : number =  Number(get);
    resolve(shouldbeNumber);
  });
}
```

Comment: `(resolve: (value: number) => void, reject)` seems to be working but I have no idea what ` => void` part does.

Comment: That's the return value. The resolve function returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of async function will always be wrapped in promise .So whether its JS or TS you cant return something which is not wrapped in `promise`.You can try something like below

```
async function makeMagic(): Promise<number> {
    let num: number;
    num = await turnIntoNumber("2");
    console.log(num);
    return num;
}
function turnIntoNumber(get:string) :Promise<number> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let shouldbeNumber : number =  Number(get);
    resolve(shouldbeNumber);
  });
}

makeMagic().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

StackBlitz [Link](https://huwjxg.run.stackblitz.io)

Comment: I tried to open the link and it not working, will you please check or update the link.